# Influencing secondary radio buttons based on primary checkbox choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have one group of checkboxes and one group of radio buttons. They are as follows:

**PRIMARY CHECKBOXES**

```
<input class="filter" type="checkbox" id="theme1" name="theme" value="adventure">
<label for="theme1">Adventure</label>
<input class="filter" type="checkbox" id="theme2" name="theme" value="attraction">
<label for="theme2">Attraction</label>
<input class="filter" type="checkbox" id="theme3" name="theme" value="leisure">
<label for="theme3">Leisure</label>
<input class="filter" type="checkbox" id="theme4" name="theme" value="culture">
<label for="theme4">Culture</label>
<input class="filter" type="checkbox" id="theme5" name="theme" value="nature">
<label for="theme5">Nature</label>
```

**SECONDARY RADIO BUTTONS**

```
<input class="filter combo" type="radio" id="combo1" name="combo">
<label for="combo1">Adv Att</label>
<input class="filter combo" type="radio" id="combo2" name="combo">
<label for="combo2">Cul Att</label>
<input class="filter combo" type="radio" id="combo3" name="combo">
<label for="combo3">Adv Nat</label>
<input class="filter combo" type="radio" id="combo4" name="combo">
<label for="combo4">Att Lei</label>
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    if ($('#theme1').is(":checked") && $('#theme2').is(":checked")) {
        $('#combo1').prop('checked', true);
    }
})
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    if ($('#theme1').is(":checked")) {
        $('#combo2').prop('checked', true);             
    }
})
```

By doing the above, there is a slight problem. When I select the **Adventure** checkbox, the **Cul Att** radio button gets highlighted. But, when I check the **Attraction** checkbox along with Adventure checkbox, I'd want the radio button to now be on **Adv Att**. I have this as a condition on my jquery code above, but it still won't work. What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't need double `.change` events for the `$(':checkbox')` elements.
2. You need to the if **two** elements are checked, and if not - check if the first is.

Here is the change:

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($('#theme1').is(":checked") && $('#theme2').is(":checked")) {
    $('#combo1').prop('checked', true);
  } else if ($('#theme1').is(":checked")) {
    $('#combo2').prop('checked', true);             
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="filter" type="checkbox" id="theme1" name="theme" value="adventure">
<label for="theme1">Adventure</label>
<input class="filter" type="checkbox" id="theme2" name="theme" value="attraction">
<label for="theme2">Attraction</label>
<input class="filter" type="checkbox" id="theme3" name="theme" value="leisure">
<label for="theme3">Leisure</label>
<input class="filter" type="checkbox" id="theme4" name="theme" value="culture">
<label for="theme4">Culture</label>
<input class="filter" type="checkbox" id="theme5" name="theme" value="nature">
<label for="theme5">Nature</label>


<input class="filter combo" type="radio" id="combo1" name="combo">
<label for="combo1">Adv Att</label>
<input class="filter combo" type="radio" id="combo2" name="combo">
<label for="combo2">Cul Att</label>
<input class="filter combo" type="radio" id="combo3" name="combo">
<label for="combo3">Adv Nat</label>
<input class="filter combo" type="radio" id="combo4" name="combo">
<label for="combo4">Att Lei</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

IF by some reason you need to keep the double event listener attached to checkboxes, you must make just a lil change:

Move

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    if ($('#theme1').is(":checked")) {
        $('#combo2').prop('checked', true);             
    }
})
```

Before

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    if ($('#theme1').is(":checked") && $('#theme2').is(":checked")) {
        $('#combo1').prop('checked', true);
    }
})
```

Why?

Currently you do:

1. You check #theme1 and #theme2
2. Callback 1 executed

   2.1 Condition: Are theme1 and theme2 both checked:

   YES - Then select **Adv Att**
3. Callback 2 executed

   3.1 Condition: Is theme1 checked

   YES - Then select **Cul Att**

So, in your code callback 1 is always overwriting callback 1.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, your duplicate callbacks are stepping on each other.

Presumably you need a solution that you can scale as you configure additional packages.

```
$('[name=theme]:checkbox').change(function() {

  var combo1 = $('#theme1').is(":checked") && !$('#theme2').is(":checked"),
  combo2 = $('#theme1').is(":checked") && $('#theme2').is(":checked");

  if(combo1) $('#combo1').prop('checked',true);
  else if(combo2) $('#combo2').prop('checked', true);

})
```

You could clean this up more with something like:

```
$('[name=theme]:checkbox').change(function() {

  var combo;
  if($('#theme1').is(":checked") && !$('#theme2').is(":checked")){
    combo = $('#combo1');
  } 
  else if($('#theme1').is(":checked") && $('#theme2').is(":checked")){
    combo = $('#combo2');
  }

  combo.prop('checked',true);

})
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/8ynhEIYGb5IIAI3GiOkb?p=preview

good luck!